# Insert rows into a table with date conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables DGS and TFIFO and i want to insert all rows having:
 date.DGS > max(date.TFIFO).

I tried

```
INSERT INTO Tabla_Fifo ( Pieza, date )
SELECT [DGS].PIEZA, [DGS].DATE
FROM TFIFO, [DSG]
WHERE ((([DSG].DATE)>Max(TFIFO.DATE)));
```

but it doesn't works.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Doesn't work how? Does the SELECT work if you run it stand-alone?

Comment: What is `Max(TFIFO.DATE))` expected to do?

Comment: gets the last date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intended to use a subquery to find the max date:

```
INSERT INTO Tabla_Fifo (Pieza, date)
SELECT [DGS].PIEZA, [DGS].DATE
FROM [DSG]
WHERE [DSG].DATE > (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM [TFIFO]);
```

I don't even see the point of joining to the `TFIFO` table, since you are only selecting values from `DSG`.  Instead, I only involve the `TFIFO` table in the subquery.